# Python: How to change a filename to lowercase but NOT the extension

Tags: python, uppercase

I'm trying to change filenames like WINDOW.txt to lowercase but then I also need to change the extension .txt to uppercase. I am thinking I can just change the entire thing to lowercase as the extension is already lowercase and then using something like .endswith() to change the extension to uppercase but I can't seem to figure it out. I know this may seem simple to most so thank you for your patience.

Comment: Split them in two, `.lowercase()` the first half, recombine. `rsplit()` is your friend.

Comment: I mean if it's always a 3 letter extension. Why not lowercase the whole thing and then uppercase the last 3 letters? If you have to deal with larger than 3 letters for the extension, that's where you need to look for the last `.` in the name.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim, you don't know it's 3 letters. `xlsx` is 4, and `gz` is 2.

Comment: Better than `(r)split` is [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yea that's explicitly why I mentioned if you absolutely know vs if you don't know. Like if you know you are only at all times dealing with txt files or if you have to accommodate multiple types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one handles filenames, paths across different operating systems:

```py
import os.path

def lower_base_upper_ext(path):
    """Filename to lowercase, extension to uppercase."""
    path, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    return head + tail.lower() + ext.upper()
```

It leaves possible directory names untouched, just the filename portion is lower-cased and extension upper-cased.

Comment: I didn't realize that `splitext()` kept the extension character in the ext part; that makes this work nicely (as demonstrated at https://ideone.com/QbqShM)

Comment: Thanks very much. That is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: I compulsively search for a suitable [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library) for *everything*. Always under my pillow are `itertools`, `collections` and `os`.

Answer (score 1):

```
oldname='HeLlO.world.TxT'
if '.' in oldname:
  (basename, ext) = oldname.rsplit('.', 1)
  newname = basename.lower() + '.' + ext.upper()
else:
  newname = oldname.lower()
print(f'{oldname} => {newname}')
```

...properly emits:

```
HeLlO.world.TxT => hello.world.TXT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "MyFile.txt"
new_name = name.rsplit(sep= ".", maxsplit=1)
print(new_name[0].lower()+"."+new_name[1].upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly, it wants the lowercase name and upper case file extension, which is weird, but here is a simple solution.

```
filename = "WINDOW.txt"
ext_ind = filename.rindex('.')
filename = filename[0:ext_ind].lower() + '.' + filename[ext_ind+1:len(filename)].upper()
print(filename)
>> window.TXT
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly for `foo.bar.baz`, nor with `foo`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for pointing it out, made changes for it to handle the situation.

Comment: I get `window.txt`, did you forget the `upper()` call on the extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "WINDOW.txt"
filename = filename.split('.')
filename = ".".join(filename[0:-1]).lower() + '.' + filename[-1].upper()
print(filename)
>> window.TXT

filename = "foo.bar.maz.txt"
filename = filename.split('.')
filename = ".".join(filename[0:-1]).lower() + '.' + filename[-1].upper()
print(filename)
>> foo.bar.maz.TXT
```